# How can I get to the "Install the printer driver" screen?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, inkjet-printer

I have an HP Envy 5530 printer. I went to "Add a printer" and selected my printer from the network. I then selected the driver from a list that looked like this:

[image]

Later, I uninstalled this printer. When I try to reinstall it, it doesn't give me the list anymore. Instead, it goes directly to this screen:

[image]

How do I make it display the list of drivers again?

Comment: Go to run and type : %SystemRoot%\INF
Search for any file that is related to your printer name and delete it then try to reinstall your printer.

Comment: I couldn't find any files with "hp" or "envy" there.

Comment: Why don't you try to download its full software (drivers should be included) and install it?

Comment: It was working before, so I know that it can work without the full software. I want to know how to get back to that one screen.

Comment: This can be done by using another windows account if you have or want to create it.

Comment: I would prefer not to create another account. Surely I can just delete a file or change a registry value or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24391/discussion-between-scorpion99-and-pikamander2).

Comment: In your start menu , go to Search and type : Print Management
Delete your printer from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. Here's how you can select the driver after you've previously selected one.

---

First, open up **Devices and Printers**.

[image]

---

Remove the printer with the incorrect drivers.

[image]

---

Click **Add a printer**.

[image]

---

You'll need the network IP of the printer. If you need it, click **Add a network, wireless, or Bluetooth printer** and write down the IP address of your printer (don't worry about the port number). Then cancel the search.

[image]
[image]

---

Now that you know the IP address of the printer, click **Add a local printer**.

[image]

---

On the Choose a Printer Port screen, click **Create a new port** and choose standard TCP/IP port from the dropdown list. Then click **Next**.

[image]

---

On the **Type a printer hostname or IP address** screen, enter the IP address of the printer. Be sure to **uncheck the checkbox**.

[image]

---

Success! Now you can select the driver that you want to use. You might have to click the **Windows Update** button if your driver isn't showing up. Once you've selected a driver, click **Next**.

[image]

---

Now **replace the current driver** and you're done!

[image]